# Location of Message Attachments in iOS 6 Backup?

Tags: macos, itunes, backup, ios, messages

I'm trying to get all my Messages (not E-Mail) and connected attachments out of a iOS 6 backup. I know there are tools like [Wondershare Data Recovery for iTunes](http://www.wondershare.com/data-recovery-mac/itunes-data-recovery.html) but they are not cheap and I'm trying to do this by my self with a self written python script.

I already know that the backups are stored here:

> ~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/

And in a specific backup (XY) the messages are stored in this file:

> ~/Library/Application
>   Support/MobileSync/Backup/XY/3d0d7e5fb2ce288813306e4d4636395e047a3d28

This is a [SQlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database file, so I can access it in different ways (e.g. SQLite Manager add-on for Firefox).

Now where are the attachments? In the messages database file above I found a table called "attachment" and "message_attachment_join" which helps to get the right attachments to a single message. But the path in "attachment" is like:

> /var/mobile/Library/SMS/Attachments/5D58C5EE-8F51-445C-A3FC-D6X94B6B6932/IMG_1230.png

I think this is the path on the iPhone. Where are all this files backuped to? In a backup directory I found three big files about 1.5 to 2.5 GB. Maybe they are stored there? But in which format, as a ZIP or TAR?

Does somebody know where I can find this files?

Comment: found a very helpfull [article](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ios-5-backups-part-1/) on iOS backup structure and a [free extract tool](http://supercrazyawesome.com/). But no answer to my question yet :)

Comment: With the tool I mentioned I can extract the filestructure like `var/mobile/Library/SMS/Attachments/*` so I'm able to get the files now, but still no clue without this extract tool. I asked the owner if he has time to answer this question.

Comment: Thank you for the updates. Don't forget, you could always answer your own question, because either way, the extractor worked for you. It might help future visitors as well.

Comment: I think that the Record structure descripted in the [article](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ios-5-backups-part-1/) is wrong. I built a PHP script like this but it doesn't work. After I used the structure of @galloglass's answer in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085153/how-to-parse-the-manifest-mbdb-file-in-an-ios-4-0-itunes-backup) it worked.

Comment: After `inode` there is a `unknown3` missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your file:

```
/var/mobile/Library/SMS/Attachments/5D58C5EE-8F51-445C-A3FC-D6X94B6B6932/IMG_1230.png
```

Replace the `var/mobile/` with `MediaDomain-` so that you end up with this:

```
MediaDomain-Library/SMS/Attachments/5D58C5EE-8F51-445C-A3FC-D6X94B6B6932/IMG_1230.png
```

Take the SHA1 hash of the above filename and that should be the name of the file in your backup: `e6f11db0844899e5f8a04a796c74c234a3dcc5bc`

To get the hash for testing, try the following link: http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm

Comment: Still works for newer paths that start with `~/Library/SMS/...` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To close this question: With this [free extract tool](http://supercrazyawesome.com/) I can extract the filestructure like: `var/mobile/Library/SMS/Attachments/*`